# ViewGroup inside CollapsingToolbarLayout show extra bottom padding when set fitsSystemWindows to be true

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an application and there is a profile fragment which shows a profile background image and some other elements. Like the screenshot below:

[image]

My question is: why there is an extra bottom padding at the end of AppBarLayout?

Here is the xml layout file of this fragment(I basically copy from Cheesesquare):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_bg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_profile_background_max"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    />

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@id/avatar"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size_large"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size_large"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/horizontal_padding_normal"
                    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                    app:civ_border_color="@android:color/white"
                    app:civ_border_overlay="false"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profile_bg"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/profile_bg"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/user_display_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_padding_small"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/horizontal_padding_normal"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_normal"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/avatar"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_padding_small"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_padding_normal"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/horizontal_padding_normal"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color_normal"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_display_name"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/vertical_divider_height"
                    android:background="@color/divider_background_color"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarSize="2dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As shown from above, I didn't add any padding to `AppBarLayout`.

I compare my layout to Cheesesquare and found that the only different is I put a complex `ConstraintLayout` inside the AppBarLayout. Cheesesquare is behaving normal because it set the `layout_height` of a certain value:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

while I am setting my `layout_height` of AppBarLayout to `wrap_content`, because the `self intro` part in the header could be a lot of words and it should be `wrap_content` to ensure every sentence can show up in the screen.

I am wondering why this extra padding show up? And FYI, I found that the height of this extra padding seems to be the same as the height of statusBar. It looks like something related to the `fitsSystemWindow` attribute. It will be nice if someone could tell me how to remove this annoying bottom padding.

ps:
I also try some other ViewGroup layout like `LinearLayout` or `Framelayout` for this area, and they are all the same, so I am pretty sure it has nothing to do with `ConstraintLayout` I use.

Comment: Have you managed to figure this one out? I'm having basically the same issue, but with a more complicated ViewGroup. The CollapsingToolbarLayout contains an ImageView, a View and a ConstraintLayout. Even if I set the View and the ConstraintLayout to visibility gone, which means only the ImageView remains (with fitsSystemWindows set to true on it) and I still have a bottom padding below the ImageView. Seriously cannot understand what's wrong with it...

Comment: No, I am still facing this issue. The only thing I can do is to set a specific height for the ImageView, just like the CheeseSquare app did. I don't understand what is going on here... @BogdanZurac

Comment: I fixed it programmatically. Just set a global layout listener on the collapsible toolbar layout, it will fire after all views have been layed out and measured. Inside just set the collapsible toolbar height to the height of the imageview or whatever you need to set it to. I know this doesn't fix the cause of the issue, but at least it fixes the outcome.

Comment: That seems like a possible workaround. It can be sure that this should be related to the the AppBarLayout's measure height progress. But I think dynamically set height to AppBarLayout may not be the perfect solution... it looks quite strange to user who want to put couple things inside AppBarLayout. Thx anyway~

Comment: @Anthonyeef https://stackoverflow.com/a/50712192/2612636

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this problem maybe caused by this [commit](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/commit/d1a3eb935cfb5deac478ac26860bcff54b21bc22#diff-1f0f6187bf553656dde3f1fb5acf3c30)

I fixed it programmatically with the way comment by @Bogdan Zurac.

```
mCollapseContentLy = findViewById(R.id.ly_collapse_content);
mCollapseContentLy.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int measuredHeight = mCollapseContentLy.getMeasuredHeight();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mCollapsingToolbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = measuredHeight;
        mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        mCollapseContentLy.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

---

### Edit after accepted

create a new class extend `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and override the `onMeasure` method

```
package android.support.design.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class GodCollapsingToolbarLayout extends CollapsingToolbarLayout {

    public GodCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public GodCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public GodCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        final int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int topInset = mLastInsets != null ? mLastInsets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() : 0;
        if (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && topInset > 0) {
            // fix the bottom empty padding
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    getMeasuredHeight() - topInset, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I finally know why that extra padding come out. Your post should be accepted answer, though ideal fix seems haven't show up...

Comment: where is mLastInsets?

Comment: It should be `lastInsets`, maybe the hungarian notation was in an earlier library version.

Answer (score 7):

Based on [@Akshay answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50712192/4099593) this is my solution:

In the xml file add android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
to:

1. CoordinatorLayout
2. AppBarLayout
3. ImageView (or other view you want to see behind the status bar. In my case it was a ConstraintLayout)

In the Activity add @Akshay answer but edit it as follow (written in Kotlin):

```
 ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(appBarLayout) { _, insets ->
        // Instead of
        // toolbar.setPadding(0, insets.systemWindowInsetTop, 0, 0)
        (toolbar.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).topMargin = insets.systemWindowInsetTop
        insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
    }
```

Now the toolbar will have the proper height as well.

Comment: This is best solution! Just to add little more explanation here: Currently CollapsingToolbarLayout logic adds status bar height to its height during onMeasure() when its layout_height is set to wrap_content and its fitsSystemWindows is set to true. If we want to avoid that, we need to set its fitsSystemWindows to false (or just don't set it, since false is default value), and we need manually to inset its children that we don't want to go under status bar. That's why we are adding top margin here to toolbar, so it stays below status bar.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a lot. Spend a lot of time and finally it got fixed

Comment: Thank you. It work for me.
But some method is deprecated.
This is my code
`ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.appBar) { _, insets ->
            (binding.toolbar.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).topMargin = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).top
            WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
        }`

Answer (score 4):

I recently faced a similar issue, this was due to the insets,as the collapsing toolbar is drawn behind the statusbar , it provides the additional height of the status bar, in order to avoid this issue, I found a better solution , instead of a calculating a height of collapse toolbar, let the toolbar consume the insets

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(appBarLayout) { v, insets ->
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            toolBar.setPadding(0, insets.systemWindowInsetTop, 0, 0)
        }
        insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
    }
```

This thing worked , instead of calculating the height
I would recommend to go through the following links

[Ian Lakes article](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec)

[Chris Banes talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mGDMVRO3iE)

Give it a try

Comment: Looks like a better answer. I will check this after work. Thank you for this solution.

Comment: You can also use setPadding

Comment: Setting padding at toolBar will make the status bar black, as status bar is being occupied by the padding of the toolBar, so instead apply margin as answered by @user3193413

Answer (score 2):

This is technically same as user3193413's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56926886/6181476) above but with non-deprecated calls:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(app_bar_layout) { _, insets ->
    val topInset = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).top
    (toolbar as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).topMargin = topInset
    WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
        }
```

Comment: If you encounter crash issue like `toolbar cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams`, you need to reference toolbar's `layoutParams`, so write `toolbar.layoutParams` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an erroneous `<View>` inside your ConstraintLayout.

This one:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/vertical_divider_height"
    android:background="@color/divider_background_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

You can remove that view if you want - it looks like it is only supplying padding or acting as a divider.

Also, you don't need to specify `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for your nested views.  Apply that attribute at the top-level view only and it will work fine.

A couple of tips that I use regularly when working with layouts are:

1) While you are developing, I find it helpful to make your views/layouts obscene colors; like hot pink, lime green, neon purple, etc... This way, you can see obvious issues with your layout and quickly identify the offending piece.  After it looks nice positionally, then you can turn the colors back to normal.

2) Turn on "show layout bounds" by [enabling on-device options through Developer Mode.](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html)  This way, you can more easily see layouts' padding and margins while designing your XML layouts.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, though it is not solving with my issue... still learn from your answer, thanks anyway.

Comment: Strange, I modified your layout and it seems to be working as expected in my project. Care to share your project with me?

Comment: you need api key and api secrect to compile this project, but I think by looking in to the `ProfileFragment.kt` source you should get the idea about what I am trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

did you try turning the layout bounds on in dev option and see which view is behind this padding, or use Layout inspector?

Comment: I tried that and it showed that it belong to the `AppBarLayout`. Also if I set the `layout_height` of `AppBarLayout`, that padding would disappear.

Answer (score 0):

**create a new class extend CollapsingToolbarLayout and override the onMeasure method**

```
public class FixCollapsingToolbarLayout extends CollapsingToolbarLayout {


    public FixCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FixCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FixCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        try {
            Field fs = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mLastInsets");
            fs.setAccessible(true);
            WindowInsetsCompat mLastInsets = (WindowInsetsCompat) fs.get(this);
            final int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int topInset = mLastInsets != null ? mLastInsets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() : 0;
            if (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && topInset > 0) {
                // fix the bottom empty padding
                heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                        getMeasuredHeight() - topInset, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtils.e(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works if I exchange "mLastInsets" with "lastInsets" -> It seems that the property was renamed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the accepted answer is not working anymore. 
You can fix it by exchanging `mLastInsets` with `lastInsets`. However it is a private field and needs to be made accessible with reflection.
Here is a Kotlin example:

```
package xxx

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Objects;

public class FixCollapsingToolbarLayout extends CollapsingToolbarLayout {


    public FixCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FixCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FixCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        try {
            Field fs = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getSuperclass()).getDeclaredField("lastInsets");
            fs.setAccessible(true);
            WindowInsetsCompat mLastInsets = (WindowInsetsCompat) fs.get(this);
            final int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int topInset = mLastInsets != null ? mLastInsets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() : 0;
            if (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && topInset > 0) {
                // fix the bottom empty padding
                heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                        getMeasuredHeight() - topInset, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Toolbar", "FixCollapsingToolbarLayout Error", e);
        }
    }
}
```